# Yandex Mapkit и кластеры

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

Подскажите кто-нибудь реализовывал кластеризацию на mapkit 3? Не могу найти ничего в интернетах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент кластеризация не поддерживается MapKit 3.